# Form Option Button Excel VBA Not Working

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to use multiple form option buttons as shown in the code below. The objective is to copy a range of data from one column and paste them and values in another column. Nothing fancy. So, I have multiple option buttons and one command button which is Button38. When I run the code, I don't get error messages and it's not working. Any help will be very appreciated, also I am new to VBA.

```
Sub Button38_Click()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheets("Sheet2").Visible = True
Sheets("Sheet2").Select

If OptionButton22 = True Then
Range("AI2:AI182").Copy
Range("AK2:AK182").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme, Operation:=xlNone _
        , SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

ElseIf OptionButton23 = True Then
Range("AD2:AD182").Copy
Range("AK2:AK182").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme, Operation:=xlNone _
        , SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

ElseIf OptionButton24 = True Then
Range("AE2:AE182").Copy
Range("AK2:AK182").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme, Operation:=xlNone _
        , SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

End If
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Sheets("Sheet2").Visible = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: What line does the error occur on? What error is it?

Comment: @BurceWayne It doesn't show any error. It's very quite. No error message.

Comment: – BruceWayne It's worth mentioning that I am not using .value in the optionbutton because I was told that I should use that with Form optionbutton. If I use .value = True. I will give error message: Object required

Comment: @Moe.A - I provided an answer, but now I see some things that may be unclear. 1) is the option button on sheet1 2) do you want to copy the range from sheet1 to sheet2? If not, please explain exactly what you want. The parentage concept I have spoken of is the right way, but I will edit my answer based on your exact needs so that you do not get stuck.

Comment: `1` Where is OptionButton22? In which sheet? `2` In which sheet is the range in? `3` Do you know how to step through the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I re-set everything to Sheet1, and sheet2. Sheet1 being the one that has the Form option buttons, and sheet2 has the columns. I want sheet2 to be hidden all time.

You are using Form Control (Option Button). Also you do not need to unhide/hide the sheets. Let it remain hidden. This code will work and the range will get copy pasted even when `Sheet2` is hidden.

Is this what you are trying?

```
Sub Button38_Click()
    Dim wsThis As Worksheet, wsThat As Worksheet
    Dim sCol As String

    Set wsThis = Sheet2 '<~~ This sheet has the range
    Set wsThat = Sheet1 '<~~ This sheet has FORM option buttons

    With wsThis
        If wsThat.Shapes("Option Button 22").OLEFormat.Object.Value = 1 Then sCol = "AI"
        If wsThat.Shapes("Option Button 23").OLEFormat.Object.Value = 1 Then sCol = "AD"
        If wsThat.Shapes("Option Button 24").OLEFormat.Object.Value = 1 Then sCol = "AE"

        .Range(sCol & "2:" & sCol & "182").Copy

        .Range("AK2:AK182").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme, _
        Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: hey you stole my `sCol` variable! ;)

Comment: Guilty as charged :P

Comment: Seriously. Good answer. It's hard to tell if it's `Form` or `ActiveX` Option button. Title says `Form`, code suggests `ActiveX` ... *me thinks its Form*

Comment: If it is a Form Control then the line `If OptionButton22 = True Then` will not give an error if `Option Explicit` is not used :)

Comment: I want to hide sheet2 where I don't want to see the it. Sheet1 has the option buttons. That is the only sheet I want to see. Now, I tried Scott Holtzman approach. It says Compiler error, method or data member are not found

Comment: I created the option buttons from the Form Controls.

Comment: @Moe.A: Please try the code that I provided. You don't need to hide Sheet2 simply because we are not unhiding it ;)

Comment: @Moe.A: Also please make up your mind. Which sheet has option buttons? and which sheet has the range that you want to copy?

Comment: `1) the option buttons are on sheet2. 2) I want to copy the range within the same sheet which is sheet1 "RESULTS". I want to copy from one column to another within the same sheet. Please ask me if something is unclear. I appreciate you help! – Moe.A 35 mins ago` @Moe.A: Under Scott's answer you said that the option buttons are in sheet2 and now you are saying that it is in sheet1????

Comment: @SiddharthRout - you feel my pain on this question!

Comment: I will ask again... Please read carefully and answer them. `1` Where is OptionButton22? In which sheet? `2` In which sheet is the range in? @Moe.A If you answer this correctly, I can show you how it works and then I can hit the sack... It is already 2:30 AM in this part of the planet :)

Comment: Apologies for the pain. I re-set everything to Sheet1, and sheet2. Sheet1 being the one that has the Form option buttons, and sheet2 has the columns. I want sheet2 to be hidden all time.

Comment: @Siddharth Rout OptionButton22 is on Sheet1

Comment: I have updated the post above. You may have to refresh the page. @Moe.A

Answer (score 0):

If you qualify all your objects to their parent the code should work. See below. (I also refactored the code a bit to make it cleaner, easier to maintain / read, and shorter).

```
Sub Button38_Click()

Dim ws1 as Worksheet
Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With Sheet2 'using the VBA sheet object name (change if needed)

    .Visible = xlSheetVisible

    Dim sCol As String

    If .OptionButton22 = True Then
        sCol = "AI"
    ElseIf .OptionButton23 = True Then
        sCol = "AD"
    ElseIf .OptionButton24 = True Then
        sCol = "AE"
    End If

   .Visible = xlSheetHidden

End With

ws1.Range("AK2:AK182").Value = ws1.Range(sCol & "2:" & sCol & "182").Value

'if you need the range theme copied as well use the code below
 'With ws1
    '.Range(sCol & "2:" & sCol & "182").Copy
    '.Range("AK2:AK182").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme, Operation:=xlNone _
    , SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
 'End With

End Sub
```

Comment: It gave me an error please see the image below: 
  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/xpJyJ.jpg

Comment: 1) the option buttons are on sheet2. 2) I want to copy the range within the same sheet which is sheet1 "RESULTS". I want to copy from one column to another within the same sheet. Please ask me if something is unclear. I appreciate you help!

Comment: @Moe.A - in your image change `Sheets("Results")` to `Sheet2` and also use my edited code above.

Comment: Nice one scott. :) I am not sure about the `.Value = .Value` part. When `XlPasteType = xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme`, Everything will be pasted using the copied range theme. `.Value = .Value` will not achieve that :)

Comment: @Scott Holtzman I have sheet2 named RESULTS and here is my code. It says object required at  .visible=True    if I delete .visible=True, it error message object required at If .OptionButton22 = True Then

Comment: Also I do not understand the point of unhiding and hiding the sheets. What purpose does that solve? @Moe.A

Comment: @Moe.A -> **1)** Change `.Visible = True ` to `.Visible = xlSheetVisible`. **2)** These are `ActiveX` option buttons, correct? On `Sheet2` named `Results` (make sure the actual VBE object name for `Results` is Sheet2. **3)** let me know if you need the `XlPasteType = xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme` back as Siddharth mentioned.

Comment: @SiddharthRout - thanks Sid. I recognized that, but intuitively felt it would work. I was waiting for OP to tell me he needed that back. I have edited the answer though to make it more complete :)